# In SAS how to display unique counts when applying proc tabulate.

Tags: sas

I am looking for a way to produce a frequency table displaying number of unique values for variable `ID` per uniqe value of variable `Subclass`.

I would like to order the results by variable `Class`.

Preferably I would like to display the number of unique values for `ID` per `Subclass` as a fraction of n for `ID`. In the want-example below this values is displayed under %totalID.

In addition I would like to display the number of unique values for `ID` per `Subclass` as a fraction of the sum of unique `ID` values found within each `Class`.  In the want-example below this values is displayed under  %withinclassID.

Have:

```
ID        Class        Subclass         
-------------------------------   
ID1        1           1a          
ID1        1           1b           
ID1        1           1c           
ID1        2           2a

ID2        1           1a           
ID2        1           1b           
ID2        2           2a           
ID2        2           2b              
ID2        3           3a

ID3        1           1a                      
ID3        1           1d 
ID3        2           2a
ID3        3           3a           
ID3        3           3b
```

Want:

```
                         Unique number   
Class       Subclass       of IDs        %totalID        %withinclassID
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1            
             1a             3             100.0             50.00 
             1b             2             66.67             33.33 
             1c             1             33.33             16.67
             SUM            6
2            
             2a             3             100.0             75.00
             2b             1             33.33             25.00
             SUM            4
3            
             3a             2             66.67             66.67
             3b             1             33.33             33.33
             SUM            3
```

My initial approach was to perform a PROC FREQ on NLEVELS producing a frequency table for number of unique IDs per subclass. Here however I lose information on class. I therefore cannot order the results by class.

My second approach involved using PROC TABULATE. I however cannot produce any percentage calculations based on unique counts in such a table.

Is there a direct way to tabulate the frequencies of one variable according to a second variable, grouped by a third variable--displaying overall and within group percentages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a double proc freq or SQL.

/*This demonstrates how to count the number of unique occurences of a variable
across groups. It uses the SASHELP.CARS dataset which is available with any SAS installation.
The objective is to determine the number of unique car makers by origin/

Note: The SQL solution can be off if you have a large data set and these are not the only two ways to calculate distinct counts.
If you're dealing with a large data set other methods may be appropriate.*/

```
*Count distinct IDs;
proc sql;
create table distinct_sql as
select origin, count(distinct make) as n_make
from sashelp.cars
group by origin;
quit;

*Double PROC FREQ;
proc freq data=sashelp.cars noprint;
table origin * make / out=origin_make;
run;

proc freq data=origin_make noprint;
table origin / out= distinct_freq outpct;
run;

title 'PROC FREQ';
proc print data=distinct_freq;
run;
title 'PROC SQL';
proc print data=distinct_sql;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `nlevels` option in `proc freq` can produce the unique count you're after without losing data, providing you include Class and Subclass variables in the `by` statement.  That also means you'll have to presort the data by the same variables.

Then you could try `proc tabulate` to get the rest of your requirement.

```
data have;
input ID $ Class Subclass $;
datalines;
ID1        1           1a
ID1        1           1b
ID1        1           1c
ID1        2           2a
ID2        1           1a
ID2        1           1b
ID2        2           2a
ID2        2           2b
ID2        3           3a
ID3        1           1a
ID3        1           1d
ID3        2           2a
ID3        3           3a
ID3        3           3b
;
run;

proc sort data=have;
by class subclass;
run;

ods output nlevels = unique_id_count;

proc freq data=have nlevels;
by class subclass;
run;
```